# Извлечь данные из вложенных json в php

Tags: php, json

Есть json строка вида:

```
$json = '
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "pages": {
            "89514": {
                "pageid": 89514,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Yahoo!",
                "thumbnail": {
                    "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Yahoo_Headquarters.jpg/50px-Yahoo_Headquarters.jpg",
                    "width": 50,
                    "height": 32
                },
                "pageimage": "Yahoo_Headquarters.jpg"
            }
        }
    }
}';
```

Хочу получить поле source на php, ввожу:

```
$yummy = json_decode($json, true);
echo $yummy['source'];
```

Естественно не выходит. Как реализовать? С простыми json справляюсь, а с вложенными не выходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На данный конкретный случай

```
$yummy['query']['pages']['89514']['thumbnail']['source'];
```

Но то такое...

Для общего случая:

```
$images = [];
foreach($yummy['query']['pages'] as $page){
    $images[] = $page['thumbnail']['source'];
}
```

На выходе массив ссылок `$images` (как понимаю, скорее всего там будет один элемент.

Если `ID` нужен, то можно так:

```
$images = [];
foreach($yummy['query']['pages'] as $id => $page){
    $images[$id] = $page['thumbnail']['source'];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!)

Comment: По хорошему - pages - это массив, и индексы там всякие могут быть и их может быть несколько элементов там - следовательно надо по нему итерировать и куда-то складывать. Но если вам надо только конкретно эту джейсонку - то пойдет и так.

Comment: Вот и столкнулся с проблемой, вот тут  "89514": {: меняется значение на каждой записи. Как мне тут можно поступить?

Comment: Ну я в предыдущем комменте примерно описал как поступать.

Comment: Обновил ответ...

Comment: Вы мастер, благодарю!